# function returns undefined in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, undefined, chart.js

I want to render a chart in AngularJS.

The service `TrendChartFactory` makes a get request to retrieve the data, having two parameters as input.

Now, **my problem is** that when I call the function `getValue()` that makes use of the data I receive from the get request **it returns undefined**.

Do you have any idea how could i fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
angular.module('App')
.directive('Trend',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/trend/trend.html',

        scope: {
           card: '=',
           puName: '<',
           selectedItem: '<'
        },
        controller: function($scope, $rootScope, $filter, TrendChartFactory) {

            $scope.$watch('selectedItem', function() {
                console.log($scope.selectedItem);
                console.log("ChangedSelected");
                TrendChart();               
            }, true);


            $scope.$watch('puName', function(){
                console.log($scope.puName);
                console.log("ChangedpuName");
                TrendChart();
            },true);

            $scope.labels = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];



            function getValue(selectedV,trendV) {

                  for(var i= 0; i< trendV.length;i++) {

                      console.log(trendV[i][selectedV]);
                      $scope.data.push(trendV[i][selectedV]);
                  }

                  $scope.datta.push($scope.data);
                  console.log($scope.datta);
            }

            function TrendChart(){

                  $scope.data = [];
                  $scope.datta = [];

                  TrendChartFactory.get( {
                    Item: $scope.selectedItem.key, 
                    puItem: $scope.puName},function(data){

                        $scope.trendValues = data;                          
                        console.log($scope.trendValues);

                  });
                  getValue($scope.selectedItem.key,$scope.trendValues);

            }
        },
        controllerAs: "TrendCtrl"
    };
})
```

Comment: You need to add $scope.getValue instead of getValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getValue($scope.selectedItem.key,$scope.trendValues);` is run before the callback inside `TrendChartFactory` is run.

You need to put this instruction inside it.

```
TrendChartFactory.get( {
  Item: $scope.selectedItem.key, 
  puItem: $scope.puName},function(data){

    $scope.trendValues = data;                          
    console.log($scope.trendValues);
    getValue($scope.selectedItem.key,$scope.trendValues);

});
```